# Combine count and join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

One of my table named `articles` having columns `id`,`category_id`,`article_text`

and in `Category` table: `id`, `parent_category` and `category_name`.

I want to  list only `parent_category` (name and total number of articles in that category) based on `article_text`. If some category has 0 in `parent_category`, means its parent category.
My query will something like this

```
select category_id from articles where article_text like '%somevalue%'
select count(category_name) from category where id=category_id
```

This query is only just to clear what to want.
Please give any idea how can achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using a subquery it will look like this :

```
select count(category_name) from category where id= (select category_id from articles where article_text like '%somevalue%);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for a list of categories with a count of the articles in each category that have a specified text (somevalue).  You can do that with a subquery:

```
select category_id,category_name,
(select count(*) from articles
    where article_text like '%somevalue%'
    AND articles.category_id = categories.category_id) as article_count
FROM Categories
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY` clause**

```
SELECT category.id,
       category.category_name,
       COUNT(articles.id) AS articles_total
FROM category
LEFT JOIN articles ON category.id=articles.category_id
WHERE articles.article_text LIKE '%somevalue%'
GROUP BY category.id;
```